# AndroidKeystore secretkey Can't init cipher

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I am using AndroidKeyStore in my app to store a secret key and I am generating that key using `KeyGenParameterSpec` class. Here's the code:

```
final SecretKey secretKey;
        final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(<validityInSeconds>)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
            .build();
        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
        secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

And after that, I am trying to init the cipher with this key:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
```

Now, AndroidKeyStore seems to have a weird issue. `cipher.init` is failing in some cases and the weird part is, I am keeping everything same/constant except trying out different values for `validityInSecs`. When it fails, it fails with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter.<init>(KeyParameter.java:13)
        at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(BaseBlockCipher.java:615)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2659)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2570)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2475)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:566)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:973)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:908)
```

I've tried with different values for `validityInSec` and it fails from some (for values which are quite low) and succeeds for some (when I increase the value). Here are some data points:

> 10s -> fail
>  1800s -> success
>  100s -> fail
>  750s ->
>   success

Another interesting thing is that for the same value, it's failing sometimes and succeeding sometimes. Examples of these values are `750s` and `625s`.

I have no clue what's going on here.

> Device: One plus 3t
>   OS: 8.0.0

Please help.

**Edit:**

The stack trace is a little misleading here, as it has traces from Spongycastle library.

That's bug in android framework classes. For a cipher, it tries with all the different providers one by one and if it fails, it stores the exception in a single variable. The problem is, it doesn't update that exception variable. So if the cipher failed for all the providers, the exception that it throws is from the first provider. So, it gives you this expression that only that provider was tried.

Here is the relevant code:
http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/javax/crypto/Cipher.java#2546

For my case, after debugging class-by-class over the success case, I found out that it IS trying other providers too apart from SC. Relevant screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried  `final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(<transformation>,"AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround");`.

Now, when I pass `duration` as `1800s`, it succeeds. And when I pass `40s`, it fails with the following error:

```
06-28 20:06:55.462 624-624/in.zeta.android E/EncryptedStoreService: android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:741)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:777)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2663)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2556)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2475)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:566)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:830)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:771)
```

- I am gonna try authenticating user just before trying to init the cipher and see if it works
- Although I do wanna solve this, In my production env, my time would anyways be `1800s`. Is it okay to forget that it fails at lower duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how the `validityInSeconds` can affect the code, but the exception does not have to do with this

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter.<init>(KeyParameter.java:13)
```

the exception is caused because the key is managed by the **AndroidKeyStore** but the `Cipher` is using the cryptographic provider **spongycastle**. The AES key is not extractable and spongycastle needs it to be able to encrypt

Remove spongycastle from your project or force to use AndroidKeyStore when you init the `Cipher`

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, "AndroidKeyStore");
```

---

The cryptographic providers are selected in order of installation in the operating system. If a cryptographic provider is not explicitly indicated, Android will select spongycastle or AndroidKeyStore according to the one above. I do not know how `validityInSeconds` affects, but there may be some internal Android behavior that changes the order

Comment: okay, but then it's working in some cases. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Did you try specifying explicitly "AndroidKeystoreProvider"? What exception was thrown in this case?

Comment: I think this problem is solved.  See my answer below. Btw, is it a general rule of thumb that key and cipher should be using the same provider. Can you recommend some good reading material for this stuff.

Comment: The reason why you saw this working for big values was that a previous authentication on the phone (maybe unlocking screen) happened in that specific timeframe. Hence making the key valid for the cryptographic operation.

Answer (score 2):

I tried

`final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(<transformation>,"AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround");`.

By putting the breakpoints, I figured out that this is the provider that actually works.

Now, when I passed `duration` as `1800s`, it succeeded. And when I pass `40s`, it failed with the following error:

```
06-28 20:06:55.462 624-624/in.zeta.android E/EncryptedStoreService: android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:741)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:777)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2663)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2556)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2475)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:566)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:830)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:771)
```

Relevant source code links from the stack trace:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/508e665/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java#215

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/83a86c5/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java#42

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java#707

Following the second link, it's not going into `KeyStore.OP_AUTH_NEEDED`, otherwise it'd have returned `null` from there. So mostly, it's in `LOCKED` state. 
(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java#58)

I understand if it needs user authentication while initing the cipher, but was curious why it's successful for the duration of `1800s`. I left my app open for > `1800s` and then tried with this duration, it failed with the same exception. And then I passed `18000s` and it worked. So, turns out it checks if user was authenticated within past `keyvalidity` secs, which perfectly makes sense, is obvious and if I am not wrong, present in docs too.

So the whole confusion was there due to the **wrong exception thrown by Cipher class** >.<

I am gonna try authenticating user just before trying to init the cipher and see if it works